# Neo4j: 'ga.nlp.ml.word2vec.addModel' not working

Tags: neo4j, word2vec

for some reasons the

> ```
> CALL ga.nlp.ml.word2vec.addModel('file:///Users/1/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database/import/numberbatch-en-17.04b.txt','file:///Users/1/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database/import/test.txt','en-numberbatch')
> ```

operation does not work for me, even though I got the result "SUCCESS".

```
CALL ga.nlp.ml.word2vec.listModels
```

does not show any records.

Any idea to solve this issue? I run the database on a Mac.

Thanks

query: CALL ga.nlp.ml.word2vec.addModel('file:///Users/1/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database/import/numberbatch-en-17.04b.txt','file:///Users/1/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database/import/test.txt','en-numberbatch')

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm facing the same challenge right now.

Comment: I got it to work on a Windows station with a newer version of neo4j et al. Now there is another folder called word2vecIndex in the import folder. With directing to this folder <path_to_index>  'CALL ga.nlp.ml.word2vec.addModel(<path_to_source_dir>, <path_to_index>, <identifier>)'